# How To Use Variable From Script In Popup

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a script where the use must enter 2 same password in order to finish their sign up. If the password match, I want to make a confirmation pop up for them to confirm their ID, which is nokppeminjam. Is it possible to use the variable in popup??

I have try some code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function validatePasswords()
   {
      var pass1=document.getElementById("idd").value;
      var pass2=document.getElementById("idd2").value;
      var nokp=document.getElementById("id").value;
      if(pass1 != pass2) 
       {
          alert("Kata Laluan Tidak Sepadan");
          return false;
       }return confirm("Sila Pastikan No. Kad Pengenalan Ialah 'nokp' Anda 
Kerana Ia Tidak Boleh Diubah Pada Masa Hadapan. Klik Ok Jika Pasti.");
      return true;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I think it would if you concatenate it. `" + nokp + "`. This isn't a PHP, HTML, or SQL question though. You are using javascript, as can be seen from `text/javascript`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function validatePasswords()
   {
      var pass1=document.getElementById("idd").value;
      var pass2=document.getElementById("idd2").value;
      var nokp=document.getElementById("id").value;
      if(pass1 != pass2) 
       {
          alert("Kata Laluan Tidak Sepadan");
          return false;
       }
       return confirm("Sila Pastikan No. Kad Pengenalan Ialah " + nokp + " Anda 
Kerana Ia Tidak Boleh Diubah Pada Masa Hadapan. Klik Ok Jika Pasti.");
       return true; // you dont need this return as it is unreachable.
  }
</script>
```

This should work.